# Сравнение времени в datetime

Tags: python

Пример кода:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

tz=timezone('Europe/Moscow')

time=datetime(2021,9,4,13,30,0,tzinfo=tz)

now=datetime.now(tz)

print(now<time)
```

Проблема со сравнением `now` и `time`.

Допустим в `time` 13 часов и 30 минут, а в `now` 13 часов и 31 минута
В итоге вывод `now<time` - `True`. Почему так, если `now` больше `time`?

Comment: Там у одной даты зона `+03:00` получается, а у другой `+02:30`, почему так - не знаю, надо копать

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо за подсказку, буду копать

Comment: Unfortunately using the tzinfo argument of the standard datetime constructors ‘’does not work’’ with pytz for many timezones. -  https://pypi.org/project/pytz/

Comment: @splash58 OK, thanks. What can be used as an alternative?

Comment: Незачем было переходить на английский. Он просто привел цитату.

Comment: @vitidev ахахах, точно.

Comment: @УтерСветоносный не подскажу - никогда не надо было :(. посмотрите для начала, что там по ссылке написано

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from pytz import timezone
>>>
>>> tz=timezone('Europe/Moscow')
>>>
>>> time=datetime(2021,9,4,13,30,0,tzinfo=tz)
>>>
>>> now=datetime.now(tz)
>>>
>>> print(now<time)
False
>>> time
datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 4, 13, 30, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Moscow' LMT+2:30:00 STD>)
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 4, 15, 37, 1, 309838, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Moscow' MSK+3:00:00 STD>)
>>> int(time)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'
>>> str(time)
'2021-09-04 13:30:00+02:30'
>>> str(now)
'2021-09-04 15:37:01.309838+03:00'
```

от сюда видим, что now имеет значене часов 15, что больше значения часов 13 time
следовательно now больше time

Comment: чел ты... Поставь в time свое время по Москве и вычти несколько минут и увидишь. Проблему я уже решил, она связана с часовыми поясами, вместо pytz использую dateutil

Comment: @УтерСветоносный если решили проблему, имеет смысл добавить ответом.

Comment: @insolor это справедливо только для разумных существ